# python irc bot to forward message

Tags: python, message, irc, forwarding

I can't make my simple bot forward what it gets in private message. 
example - my bot gets in the message "I need a good sleep tomorrow" then my bot needs to forward on a specific channel the message.

How can I achieve this?

```
    import socket
from random import *
beenShot = False
count = randint(0, 5)
network = 'irc.p2p-network.net'  
channel = "#channel"   
nick = 'nick'   
password = 'pass' 
nickserv = 'NickServ'
System = 'System'
channel2 = "#chan2"
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((network, port))
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' ' + nick + ' ' + nick + ' ' + ':YoByMe\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')
irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + nickserv + ' :identify pass\r\n')
while True:
    data = irc.recv(128) 
    if data.find('PING') != -1:
        irc.send('PONG ' + data.split()[1] + '\r\n')
    if data.find('KICK') != -1:
        irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')
    if data.find('!!!bot quit') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :Alright, I\'ll quit then...\r\n')
        irc.send('QUIT\r\n')
    if data.find('!!!hello' or '!hi') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :Hello\r\n')
    if data.find('!!!help') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :All commands begin with ! and are as follows: '
                                        'hi / hello, slap, 8ball / 8b, and russianRoulette / rr\r\n')
    def ask():
        ask_responses = ["Yes", "No"]
        #Prints to the IRC chat
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + choice(ask_responses) + '\r\n')
    def eightBall():
        ball_responses = ......
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + choice(ball_responses) + '\r\n')
    def russianRoulette():
        global count
        global beenShot
        gun_responces = ['*Click*', '*Click*', '*Click*', '*Click*', '*Click*', '*BANG*']
        if beenShot:
            irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' *Reloading*\r\n')
            count = randint(0, 5)
            beenShot = False
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + gun_responces[count] + '\r\n')
        if count == 5:
            beenShot = True
        else:
            count += 1
    if data.find('!!!slap') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :Come on man, why you got to be like that?\r\n')
    if data.find('!!!ask' or '!a') != -1:
        ask()
    if data.find(',!!!8b' or ',!8ball') != -1:
        eightBall()
    if data.find('!!!rr' or '!russianRoulette') != -1:
        russianRoulette()
    if data.find('please choose a different nick') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + nickserv + ' :identify pass\r\n')
    if data.find('INVITE nick') != -1:
      irc.send('JOIN ' + channel2 + '\r\n')
    if data.find('nick :show') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + System + ' :show\r\n')
```

Comment: Please post some example code and the errors you are getting.

Comment: i don”t have code or error .... i try what i can find on the internet and not working .... this is my .py

Comment: please edit your post to include your code,  only using offsite links is not acceptable.

Comment: i don't know enough about IRC to help you and it appears you aren't getting other responses...maybe do some more research and post some things you tried and the results...